How do I handle guilt after yelling at my child?
I'm a father of two, and my eldest child is 4 years and 2 months old. I work from home while caring for my first child, and today I feel like I overreacted and yelled at them.
This has been building up over the past week because my child has been very difficult when it comes to eating, and I've been feeling frustrated. Additionally, I feel some anger toward my wife's family, as my child tends to get sick every time I pick them up to stay with me.
Two weeks ago, my child was hospitalized for a urinary tract infection (UTI), and this week they've been complaining of pain and having fevers every night. I'm confused and overwhelmed with guilt over my actions today.
What should I do to address this guilt and manage my emotions better? I'm really struggling with feelings of confusion and regret.

Although this question addresses your feelings about your behavior towards a child, the real answer(s) involve your ability to regulate your emotions. Are you open to an answer that addresses anger issues rather than one that assuages your feelings of guilt? (it's likely you might get angry with the answer as well, for good reason; not because it's an attack on you, but because anger is often the response to any kind of hurt.)

TL;DR: Apologize, always. Use feeling words in your apologies, own your actions, identify with your child's feelings about it, and tell him you're working on being a better dad to him and a better person. Then work on anger management by understanding how emotions work.
This is a difficult question requiring a long answer, sorry. It's not meant to attack you; I had to work on this as well.
Guilt that you feel spontaneously when you've done something you know is wrong is appropriate, and you should feel it. It's a good sign that you do. It means you can empathize with the child you lost your temper with.
Emotions are complex things, and often they are not what they seem superficially. Learning about emotions, primary and secondary, their labels, examining your own emotions carefully, identifying primary and secondary emotions, and teaching your child the language of emotions will help both of you, a lot.
Primary emotions are the very first thing you feel in a given situation. Sometimes they are obvious and recognizable to us (like joy or surprise) and sometimes they're not (like helplessness or inferiority). To recognize primary emotions requires a degree of openness and vulnerability, especially to the painful ones. Secondary emotions are what you feel after the first emotion.  You can't control your primary emotions, but you can change the way you react on feeling the secondary emotions. (Sometimes, like with joy, the primary emotion is the same as the secondary emotion.)
An example: a friend jumps out from hiding and startles me. I instantly feel fear (or surprise). Fear is a primary emotion. I can't control it, I can't help feeling it. How I "react" to fear (it's a bit more complicated than reacting; it's a feeling as well, and it registers on my face) is a secondary emotion, and that emotion depends on who I am, my present emotional and physical state, my past experiences, etc. If my brother did it maliciously all. the. time., my secondary reaction will be anger, annoyance, or some other negative emotion, even rage. If I was in a good place emotionally at the moment, or it's a joke I understand or not something done to annoy me previously, my secondary emotion might be amusement. You can't control primary emotions, but secondary emotions can be modified with work.
Anger is more complex. Though some psychologists call it a primary emotion, others call it a secondary one, because it usually is. I understand it and experience it as a secondary emotion. Anger is a feeling resulting from something painful to us. Why do we swear when we hit our thumbs with a hammer? Because it hurts, and it could have been prevented with care, so we are angry.
Some primary emotions are just as painful as, or more so than, a hammer to the thumb. Feeling insignificant is painful. Feeling slighted, less than, helpless, confused, intimidated, unwanted, disrespected, and a bunch of other things is painful. Painful emotions are difficult to handle. For that reason, before we even realize it, *they cause a secondary emotion: anger, anxiety/fear, sadness or others. Anger is a common one, and is easier to handle than pain because it redirects that discomfort outward towards someone/thing else; it feels like power, it energizes. It's a 'solution' of sorts to our pain.
Parents get angry at their kids for all kinds of reasons, usually in response to a painful primary emotion that's difficult to handle in the moment. Setting aside justified anger, an example: my young child has an ear infection. She wakes up frequently at night, interrupting my sleep. I'm tired. She's cranky and demanding, which is draining my energy and my patience. When I try to give the child her antibiotic, which tastes terrible, the child justifiably fights me. I get angry with her. Why?
My reserves are down. Additionally, I feel helpless, hopeless, and afraid (all painful primary emotions I can't control), because she's ill and giving her an antibiotic is, I believe, the only thing that will make her better. I desperately want her to get better (for both our sakes!). Helplessness and hopelessness are incapacitating, so it quickly elicits my secondary emotion: anger. Anger is directed at an identifiable target: her behavior/her person. I feel enabled. I feel power to do something. I yell. I say mean things. I make excuses for my meanness; I blame her. And when that anger passes, I feel guilt and shame, both of which also hurt, not to mention the many painful feelings my child, who depends on me for comfort, safety and love, is experiencing. It's all just horrible.
The answer to anger is to cultivate calmness and to recognize/be open to feeling helpless, hopeless, fearful, and every other painful emotion. It's better than emotionally hurting your child.
What would success look like? Same scenario, and child spits out the medicine I tried to bribe, then force, her to take. I'm angry, but I do nothing for a moment and try to identify the feelings I had before I felt angry. Contemplating the pool of medicine, I realize I feel helpless, hopeless, physically tired, and fearful for her health. I say, "I'm so tired, honey, and I want so much for you to get better. You must take this medicine, even though it tastes bad, or I'm afraid you will get worse. Can you try again?" ("Pinch your nose/here's some juice to wash away the flavor/then we can watch a movie together, do you want ice cream or popcorn?"/whatever else might be helpful.) "I don't want to force you, but you will not win this one. You need to take this medicine, now or in 5 minutes, no exceptions."
This course of action shows love for the child, empathy and respect for her feelings, and outlines the situation. It also teaches her that you have feelings, too, and that feeling pain, fatigue, helplessness and fear is normal and nothing to be ashamed of. It doesn't harm her in any way.
That's really the answer. You were under a lot of strain, and have been for a while (I suspect quite a while, intermittently at least): you were taking care of a sick, cranky child by yourself, and you were fearful for your child's health and feeling somewhat helpless to protect them when he is with your wife's family. I mean, what's going on that he gets sick so often? What are they doing??? He just got out of the hospital with a UTI for @!#&^$#{} sake! And he's still sick! This is so. stinking. HARD! [And you live with that right there in the moment. The more you do this, the easier it will become to rest with your primary emotion(s) and not to get angry/other harmful emotion. Really. It's hard work but the benefits are immense.]
There are a lot of answers on this site detailing the benefits of teaching your child empathy, emotional literacy, resilience, etc. Search the site and read them. There's less about self-care as a parent. Read about that too, wherever you can find it. Read about anger management, how to apologize meaningfully, how to turn guilt and shame into a learning experience, and finally, how to forgive yourself and how to ask for forgiveness. Don't worry about appearing weak. Worrying about how others perceive us is a recipe for unhappiness. Figure out what you can do (why he gets sick so often) and do what you can about it. (Keep records, too; you may need them.) And please know that we all fail our children, and that asking for help and working at being better is the right response. Good luck.
What’s The Difference Between Primary And Secondary Emotions?
Unconscious emotional processing
Control anger before it controls you

Yes. It's normal to overreact or do dumb things as parents, the way to fix these missteps is to sincerely apologize to your kid. You wouldn't believe how much respect it'll earn you from them.

@Cdn_Dev  100%. A sincere apologies is so valuable in its own right, above and beyond being the best way to fix something. A child can't learn any of this stuff from a "perfect" parent who never makes mistakes. By acknowledging when you mess up, and modelling how to discuss and apologise for it, you normalise being human and also teach your child how to communicate, express their feelings and rebuild relationships.

According to Caroline Goldman (known in France for her books on child psychology and psychology for children) a child who is genuinely loved, knows the difference between a parent who is tired and a mistreating parent. In other words, the children quickly understand that occasional angry outbursts from their parents do not mean that they are unloved. You can notice yourself how quickly a child forgets about the dispute and comes to play/joke with you again.
I don't think apologizing makes much sense - at least not in the sense one would apologize to an adult. It simply involves many concepts that I child might not be familiar with (at the age of 4) - guilt, correct ways of social behavior, etc. On the other hand, explaining that daddy/mommy was tired and reacted in an unusual way, and that they will be kinder next time is necessary - this way the child actually learns about the acceptable norms of social behavior (though do not hold your breath that they internalize it quickly.)
Finally, accept that there will be always times when you crack and lash against your children. As long as you do not do them physical or mental harm, it is inevitable, especially if you are working full time, or taking care of several children, or otherwise find yourself under stress. (By mental harm I mean things like deliberately humiliating them - not simply screaming or punishing for a well-understood reason.) It is a good idea to observe (and discuss with) other parents - you will quickly notice that they have similar problems.

I fully agree - I think a child that age just want their parent to become nice again, so a even just hug may be enough.

...not simply screaming or punishing for a well-understood reason." I disagree, respectfully, because I agree with a lot of your answer. A 4 year old is helpless against an adult. Furthermore, they depend on said adult for everything, including safety and their developing self-esteem. Losing control is scary to the recipient of an angry outburst. A sincere apology is warranted whether a child or another adult is involved. Pride is what holds people back from apologizing. Kids learn from their parents, and that we make kistakes we're sorry for isn't a bad lesson at all.

"You can notice yourself how quickly a child forgets about the dispute and comes to play/joke with you again." When I get angry at my dog, the first thing my dog does is to come to me, eyes holding contact with mine, tail wagging, to curry my favor. That's not love, that's self preservation. They are not the same thing. It's a serious mistake to confuse them. Kids learn self-preservation behavior, too.

@anongoodnurse I think a simple rule-of-thumb is whether the child already knows to apologize themselves - IMHO this is not very common for 4y.o. This is why I suggest meaningful explanation of the parent behavior rather than a formal apology, which makes the parent feel better, but not the child. In a way, I do recommend apologizing (rather than just pretending that nothing happened), but in a way adapted to the child's level.

That's reassuring to know, thanks. How, though, is a child to learn how to apologize if it's not in normal language? I agree it needs to be understandable to the child, but "I'm sorry" needs to be in there. A "formal apology" isn't the same as a formulaic "I'm sorry full stop" apology where there is no grief, no ownership, no regret, no empathy, no promise to try harder. We all deserve more.

@anongoodnurse What bothers me personally in a full apology is that the parent puts themselves on the same level as the child... which is false, and might even make the child feel insecure. Indeed, the child should not be mislead about the fact that the parent has the authority, and that sometimes (or rather often) the child should obey, even if they do not understand why the parent demands this from them. I am not sure that a dog is capable of understanding that the owner has its interests at heart, but this kind of reassurance is essential for a child. Don't you think so?

Good question. I guess it depends on one's parenting style. Kids aren't miniature adults, for sure. But I lean on the Permissive side of Authoritative. It sounds like you might be leaning on the Authoritarian side of Authoritative. To put it into some context (maybe) for you, I apologize to my dogs, lol! Maybe only because I want to feel better. Never thought of it that way.

@anongoodnurse Some things a non-negotiable or hardly negotiable - like behaving in a street with a car traffic, playing with sharp objects and electrical appliances, or getting up and dressing in time for school. On the other hand, how they hold knife/fork or which clothes they put on is not worth making fuss about. Is that Permissive or Authoritarian?

@RogerV. I personally think that parents should model the way that they want their child to behave.
Do you want your kid to feel genuine contrition when they make a mistake, own up to that mistake, try to make it right, and try to change their behavior? Or do you want them to just justify their behavior and not try to change it. Which is what your answer reads as to me.

TLDR. You are the role model for your child. How you behave will teach your kid how they should behave. You want your kid to apologize? You gotta do the same.

@Questor this strikes me as a rather partial reading of my answer. I suggest that you re-read it... and apologize for you self-righteous tone. Then perhaps I will believe that you are able to apologize to your kids.

I had answered but deleted, sorry. I'd say you're Authoritative, maybe with Permissive leanings. We are much more alike than different. My parents were Authoritarian (communication was mostly one way; I wasn't allowed to question them) and I rejected that completely. It's not fun to be a kid with authoritarian parents. That's probably why I place so much emphasis on apologies, too.

@anongoodnurse I see your point. As you could guess from my earlier comments, I do not consider social conventions as the main objective of education, even if they are certainly a part of it. Sometimes a person may be irritable/angry/aggressive because they are tired, stresses, sick - not because they do not like us or because we did something wrong. Many such situations require our understanding, rather than their apology. Another point is that changing one's ways is more important and more difficult than stepping over one's pride and apologizing.

@anongoodnurse as another side of apology: when I imagine authoritarian parents, I think of people who constantly force their child to apologize, say hello/goodbye, sit and eat in certain way, etc.  Whenever I see a polite and well-behaved little child, I feel uneasy.

Consider time outs for yourself
Others have mentioned the need to apologize and I agree with those sentiments. I've written about that for another question, but I think the general advice is broadly applicable.
Anongoodnurse's answer hits on something I think that's really important, self-care as a parent. In order to make things viable for yourself so that you don't get overwhelmed, consider either putting your kid or yourself in a timeout if the situation is causing you to become increasingly frustrated. There's a good Bluey episode on this called Sheepdog where Mommy, "just need 20 minutes when no-one says anything to me." It is very relatable.
This is something my wife and I did throughout the pandemic at times just to have some space where we weren't trying to logically negotiate with the whims of a cranky 3-year old. Either me or her would just go to our room, close the door, and the other parent kept the kids from pestering us.
When I did this for myself, a lot of times I'd just pace the room, huff a bit to myself, and eventually pull my feelings down enough to sit on the bed and meditate a bit. In general, the only other thing I might've irritated in that space was my cat because she was sometimes conscripted to sit on my lap and purr during my meditation.
Given you seem to be in a single parent situation, I would advise you to explain to your daughter that you'll do this sometimes when you just need to take a break to think. It will greatly depend on your child's own temperament whether she can avoid pestering you during this time. For my eldest, she would not continue pestering me, conversely my son would probably be in the hall outside my door hitting it with a toy hammer without someone intervening, so your mileage may vary. Hopefully, if you include this discussion with the previously mentioned apology, she will be able to make the connection that she's more likely to experience mean words if she bothers you when you're trying to avoid saying those words.

I think anongoodnurse's advice is sound: Apologize. Don't panic. Explain a bit why you were frustrated. Children are often surprisingly sweet and forgiving. Don't chastise yourself.
To me it's always important to be "authentic", even if that word sounds more and more awful the more overused it becomes. But at the core it's important to not pretend too much because children learn most from what we actually do and less from what we say. If we always hide our feelings in order to manipulate other people that will be what they learn.
[The following considerations are based on the understanding that what annoyed or angered you wasn't that your child felt sick and therefore had no appetite etc., but behavior it would have (however limited, at the age of 4) control over.]
We don't know how much you yelled and how forceful, but if it was just a normal angry reaction I think that's not the end of the world. If it is any consolation: your outbreak was a genuine reaction and may be more valuable than a strained, self-controlled mechanical textbook response. Your child did anger you, after all, and it got feedback. (That said, I feel the need to say that you don't want to traumatize it or deeply scare your (or any) child, lest I get accused of sanctioning child abuse.)
And your regret about the episode is also genuine and the child will understand that as well.
As an aside, you are in a difficult situation on multiple fronts which may need to change. The detail of fussy eating is annoying and delicate at the same time and is connected to attention seeking and self-assertion etc. which makes it hard to tackle. You are welcome to ask about some of the problems here — you are hardly the only overworked parent in a patchwork family and a complicated relationship to your Ex!

Thanks, Toby! No, the eating was (to my knowledge) not fuzzy ;-).

You don't know why the child wasn't eating, but I can tell you that lack of appetite is common when sick and feverish. To interpret it as attention seeking which deserves a correction ("Your child did anger you, after all, and it got feedback.") is indicative of a fairly impressive lack of understanding on your part. The child wasn't jumping on the couch. He/she was sick. Loss of appetite is normal (not an attention grab!) While the rest of your answer is fine, that deserves a DV, so -1 from me.

On reflection, the rest of your answer isn't fine. You correctly pointed out that kids learn from our behavior, not our words. So, so true. What do you want the child to learn? That it's not ok to experience lack of appetite at 4 years of age? That a normal, authentic state of being is unacceptable if it irritates an adult? That getting angry is better than being in control of our emotions? Great lesson to learn. Kudos.

@anongoodnurse Maybe I misunderstood -- I had read "has been very difficult when it comes to eating" as an independent issue. Of course, if it's not eating because it feels sick, there is no use in getting angry. I also interpreted "difficult when it comes to eating" not as "no appetite". My opinion was based on that.

Still, kudos for assuming the worse of 4 year olds, sick or not, and for your attitudes in general towards children and controlling one's emotions. Why be fake when we're actually angry (i.e. how does self-restraint help anyone)? Is it fine to be angry at a 4 year old when "it" is irritating? Authenticity as you use it equals cruelty.

I disagree with this a lot... Yes it is important to be genuine. But guess what, the 4 year old, was being genuine. They didn't want to eat. As a 4 year old (which is still a baby) they lack the communication skills/emotional intelligence to explain why they aren't eating/don't want to eat. So to an adult it can look like the kid is just playing with their food, when all their parent wants to do is finish dinner, brush teeth and stick the kid in bed. So I don't get what you are saying, which is more important... the genuine reaction of a parent iriratated with their kid not eating.

Or the genuine reaction of the kid who is sick and so doesn't feel hungry.
Do you want to teach the kid to mask their genuine feelings so that the adult doesn't lose control of their temper? Or isn't it better that the adult be the adult in the situation, control their emotions like an adult  and be the bigger person ;)

Emotional control doesn't mean that a person isn't authentic... It means that a person has emotional maturity, and self mastery..

"But guess what, the 4 year old, was being genuine. They didn't want to eat." YES, thank you, @Questor. The double standard is harsh.

"...if it's not eating because it feels sick, there is no use in getting angry." So getting angry seems to be a useful tool for you. How interesting, and interesting also that you would use this tool on a 4 year old for any reason not life-threatening, like picky eating. Poor child.


I feel like I overreacted and yelled at them.

Being a parent is hard work. It is physically, mentally, and emotionally taxing. All parents make mistakes. If this is the first time you have overreacted to your childs behavior, you are doing a pretty good job. It probably won't be the last.
You have recognized that you made a mistake
That is a good first step.
The 2nd step is harder. And that is to demonstrate the behavior that you want your child to emulate when they have an emotional outburst.
You are your kids hero, their role model. Everything that you do and say, they will do and say. It is times when you make a mistake as a parent that you can provide your kid the most important life lessons.
Which are 1) Even daddy/mommy make mistakes, 2) its what you do after you make a mistake that defines you.
So go to your child, own what you did, apologize for yelling at them, and make sure that they know that you love them and then try to be better in the future. That's about all you can do.
As the parent you could even turn this into a conversation about how we all have emotions, sometimes we are angry, or sad. And talk about what is the proper way to express these emotions instead of losing control and yelling. And then you can talk about how sometimes we make mistakes and how important it is to admit to our mistakes and try to fix them. Dressed down to language appropriate to a 4 year old.
TLDR: Your child will do what you do. Show your kid how to behave, how to apologize.

It is reassuring for the parents that they can absolve their guilt by going through the apology ritual that the child does not even understand. And that they can raise a child to behave in the way they like. What about the needs of the child?

@RogerV. - Kids usually understand a lot more than we give them credit for. If I say to a young child, e.g. "I am so sorry for yelling at you. That must have been scary. It was wrong of me to yell, and you didn't do anything bad, even, I'm so sorry." Do they know what sorry means? Maybe, maybe not, but they can intuit the meaning by the expression of sorrow on my face, my conciliatory tone, etc. And they hear me acknowledge their feelings, valuing them and their emotional state(s). How can that be bad? I just can't see it.

@anongoodnurse kids not only understand, but they constantly learn about the world. Here is what my inner child says: "So you aggressed me for no reason, and now you feel guilty and try to buy yourself out by apologizing and offering gifts. It means I should be ready for a similar aggression at any moment. Nothing can stop you, because you can easily buy forgiveness by saying sorry. And in case of an external danger you will always prioritize your personal emotional well-being over my interests."

@anongoodnurse in the end, what we really disagree about is whether the words sorry and apology are essential in the explanation that we give to the child, and about the need for parent to feel guilty - there is a lot of social pressure in this thread that they should feel guilty. To me the author of the Q. looks like a stressed and overloaded parent, who simply needs reassurance that their occasional outburst would not do serious harm.

@RogerV.- I disagree intensely. Yours is a very cynical view. You project the thoughts/experience of the child to whom an apology is given in the most problematic and selfish way possible. True grief is appreciated by injured parties; it validates their feelings and their worth. If the apology is hollow, the child may well interpret it the way you said. I've never, ever given a hollow apology to my kids. About guilt, the OP feels it, and appropriately so. Do you know who doesn't feel guilt on acting antisocially? Sociopaths. Seriously. Guilt is a normal emotion.
